# How to find index of nearest geometry

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, shapely

This code is finding the nearest point for each element within the defined Geodataframe. I need to find the nearest point index beside its geometry. (efficiency matters)

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(['Street A', Point(1,1)], 
                       ['Street B', Point(2,2)],
                       ['Street C', Point(3,3)],
                       ['Street D' ,Point(4,4)]], 
                      columns=['STREET','geometry'])

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    point = row.geometry
    multipoint = df.drop(i, axis=0).geometry.unary_union
    queried_geom, nearest_geom = nearest_points(point, multipoint)
    print(queried_geom)
    print(nearest_geom)
    #index = ???
```

So I can access the nearest point record using its index

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line:

```
match_geom = df.loc[df.geometry== nearest_geom]
```